# How do I preset a file upload that is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 file uploads that only allows a user to choose images. The probem is, whether or not a user chooses a picture with a file upload, I get the default "Images/noImage.jpg" path saved to my database. I also believe I understand why. I preset the `filename` variables to `""` or an empty string. Here is where I get confused, if I set the `filename` variables to the value of the fileupload I get a "object not set to instance of an object" error, telling me that its looking for a value that is not there. Here is what I tried:

```
        //ImageAlt labels current Text is set to 'Images/'
        string ImgPath1 = lblImageAlt1.Text.ToString();
        string ImgPath2 = lblImageAlt2.Text.ToString();
        string ImgPath3 = lblImageAlt3.Text.ToString();   

        //Get Filename from fileupload control
        string filename1 = ""; 
        string filename2 = ""; 
        string filename3 = ""; 

        if (fileuploadimages1.HasFile)
        {
            filename1 = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages1.PostedFile.FileName);
            fileuploadimages1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ImgPath1 + filename1));                 
        }
        else
        {
            filename1 = "noImage.jpg";
        }

        if (fileuploadimages2.HasFile)
        {
            filename2 = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages2.PostedFile.FileName);
            fileuploadimages2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ImgPath2 + filename2));                
        }
        else
        {
            filename2 = "noImage.jpg";
        }

        if (fileuploadimages3.HasFile)
        {
            filename3 = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages3.PostedFile.FileName);
            fileuploadimages3.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ImgPath3 + filename3));
        }
        else
        {
            filename3 = "noImage.jpg";
        }

        //Save images into Images folder
        fileuploadimages1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ImgPath1 + filename1));
        fileuploadimages2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ImgPath2 + filename2));
        fileuploadimages3.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ImgPath3 + filename3));
        //Getting SiteSqlServer2 from web.config connectionstring
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnection1"].ToString());

        //Open the database connection
        conn.Open();

        //Query to insert images path and name into database
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into my_db(CreateDate,ItemName,ItemType,ImageSrc1,ImageAlt1,ImageSrc2,ImageAlt2,ImageSrc3,ImageAlt3,ItemDescription,ItemPrice,FName,LName,ContactNum,AltContactNum,IsApproved,IsExpired,Email,IsRejected) values(@CreateDate, @ItemName, @ItemType, @ImageSrc1, @ImageAlt1, @ImageSrc2, @ImageAlt2, @ImageSrc3, @ImageAlt3, @ItemDescription, @ItemPrice, @FName, @LName, @ContactNum, @AltContactNum, @IsApproved, @IsExpired, @Email, @IsRejected)", conn);

        //Passing parameters to query
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", CreateDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", ItemName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemType", ItemType);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageSrc1", filename1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageAlt1", ImgPath1 + filename1);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageSrc2", filename2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageAlt2", ImgPath2 + filename2);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageSrc3", filename3);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageAlt3", ImgPath3 + filename3);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemDescription", ItemDescription);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemPrice", ItemPrice);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", FName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", LName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNum", ContactNum);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AltContactNum", AltNum);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsApproved", isApproved);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsExpired", isExpired);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsRejected", isRejected);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Close
        conn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("form.aspx");

    }
```

As mentioned earlier the images will upload properly if the image path is set to `filename1 = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages1.PostedFile.FileName);....` but I should be able to make exceptions for users who do not wish to add all 3 or only 1 or 2 or none at all.

Comment: Where is your insert into database code?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your problem but would it not be possible to move your individual `SaveAs()` statements inside of the various `if` blocks so that each of the `SaveAs()` becomes conditional? Then you decide what the condition for save should be...

Comment: @Skullmania - Your code is working. `filename3` is a `null` string and thus the default value `noImage.jpg` is used.  You should be checking if fileuploadimages1.PostedFile.FileName is a `null` instead of your local variable.

Comment: I edited the code to add db code and the SaveAs() as requested.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried your suggestion and still could not get it to function properly.

Comment: @Skullomania - Post your implementation of my suggestion.

Comment: It was the same as Mark Redmans, and you were both correct. The reason why it was not functioning correctly is because of an update panel on the front end. I am not sure as to why the update panel would cause the fileupload to make `hasfile = false` but it looks like I have more research to do on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check if the `FileUpload` component has a file, using `fileuploadimages1.HasFile`

Also, you cannot preset the `FileUpload` component with a preselected file if you are trying to do that?

Comment: its not the file upload persay its the value that it has...if the `fileupload` value is blank then set the value to `noImage.jpg`. That actually works, however, when a user selects an image that image does not want to save. I will try the `fileuploadimages1.HasFile` thanks.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and edited the original post to show. I am still having the same issues.

Comment: It looks like your code is trying to save the images twice, remove the lines after the checks... remove the 3 lines after the comment "//Save images into Images folder" those may cause an error?

Comment: The reason why it was not functioning correctly is because of an update panel on the front end.